# Change UICollectionViewCell size when a cell is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have drawn UICollectionView [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/733ubsvmvh910ea/232.jpg).
When the user taps on a cell I want it to look something [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5fwem8kbibcv2a5/123.jpg)

Basically I want to enlarge the tapped cell and the other cells will move in the next row.

Any suggestions how to implement this ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` instead of just using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I create new git repository for your problem. Please try it https://bitbucket.org/banumelody/uicollectionview-resize-cell-on-tap

I hope it can help you.